# show image based on presence of a URL

Tags: php, image, url, foreach, fopen

I would like to add an image in case a URL is present/active. Ive tried many things myself to make it work but without success.

What I want is: if url1 exist show image1 else nothing, if url2 exist show image2 else nothing, etc.

```
foreach ($urlsArray as $url) {
  if(@fopen($url,'r')){
    echo 'Exist';
  }
  else {
      echo 'Doesnt exist';
  }
}
```

Sorry I have to be more specific!

```
$urlArray = array(
'http://www.domain.com/page1.php' => 'images/image1.jpg',
'http://www.domain.com/page2.php' => 'images/image2.jpg', 
etc);

foreach($urlsArray as $url){
    if(@fopen($url,'r')){
        echo '<img src="$image" />' /* if url1 exist show image1, etc */
    }else{
        echo '';  
    }
}
```

How to get this to work?

Comment: What do you mean with "add an image to a url"?

Comment: What does your code show as output now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that `$url = path/to/pic/pic.gif` - meaning that url actually leads to a pic to be displayed

```
foreach ($urlsArray as $url) {
  if(@fopen($url,'r')){
    echo '<img src="'.$url.'" />';
  }
}
```

---

updated (use $key => $value for your foreach):

```
foreach ($urlsArray as $url => $img)  {
  if(@fopen($url,'r')){
    echo '<img src="'.$img.'" />';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help ?:

```
<?php

foreach($urlsArray as $url){
    if(!empty(file_get_contents($url))){
        echo "exist";
    }else{
        echo "Doesn\'t exist";  
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To the extent of my knowledge and past experience `fopen` for an external URL requires `allow_url_fopen` to be set to On. Normally it would be disabled as a security measure in deployment environments, suggest using some alternate method like [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) to check the URL is present or not with the http response code returned. Then proceed to show or not show the image based on the response code.

Sample code:

```
$url_exists_1 = check_url($url1);
if ($url_exists_1) {
  // show image 1;
}
else {
  // don't;
}
function check_url($url='') {
  if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
    die("Please enable curl");
  }
  $curl_options_array = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 5
  );
  if ($url != '') {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curl_options_array);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ($code == 200) {
      return TRUE;
    }
    else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  } 
  else {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

Comment: The behaviour of these functions is affected by settings in php.ini.

Comment: @Learner yes, `allow_url_include` and `allow_url_fopen` is disabled in php.ini in most cases as it could be used for [Remote file inclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_File_Inclusion). cURL is a viable alternative.

Comment: if the url exists the `$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);` would be 200 (HTTP OK status code) thereby returning TRUE, so you know the URL exists.